# In App Purchase (IAP) simple questions (I have an issue)

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I've checked tremendous checklists and I've tried all the possible solutions, but my IAP never works! (Just have the last solution: re-start whole procedure including generate new App ID)

My Checklist:

- V Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID? : Of course
- V Have you checked Cleared for Sale for your product? : At the beginning
- V Have you submitted (and optionally rejected) your application binary? : My app is already on App Store and is being sold.
- V Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID? : Sure, so that I can sell my App with Distribution profile.
- V Have you generated and installed a new provisioning profile for the new App ID? : Twice! (not my User Certification Profile)
- V Have you configured your project to code sign using this new provisioning profile? : Sure
- V Are you building for iPhone OS 3.0 or above? : I use iPhone4 and build for iOS3.0
- V Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest? : I tried both full ID and without prefix.
- V Have you waited several hours since adding your product to iTunes Connect? : It's been more than 3 whole days.
- V Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect? (via Mark) : Bank, Tax, and all three contracts are in effect. (How can I know that bank detils are 'active'? I filled all the blanks and submitted)
- V Have you tried deleting the app from your device and reinstalling? (via Hector, S3B, Alex O, Joe, and Alberto) : Many times... deleted reinstalled remove all profiles reinstalled... disconnect, reboot and so on...
- my IAP status is 'Waiting for Screenshot'
- Clean and rebuild : tried
- Make a new product ID : tried
- Make a new test user : tried (and logout my own account)
- Make a new AdHoc provisioning profile : tried
- I used explicit app ID
- You did not complete all the financial requirements (see the "Contracts, Tax, and Banking Information" section of this document). : YES
- You did not use an explicit App ID. : I used explicit ID like com.app.myapp (and com.app.myapp.product1 for my product id)
- You did not use the Provisioning Profile associated with your explicit App ID. : I use correctly so that my app is on the appstore.
- You did not use the correct product identifier in your code. See Technical Q&A, QA1329, 'In App Purchase Product Identifiers' for more information about product identifiers. : Checked checked checked checked copy and paste.....
- You did not clear your In App Purchase products for sale in iTunes Connect. : I checked.
- You might have modified your products, but these changes are not yet available to all the App Store servers. : been 48 or more hours..
- If you or App Review rejected your most recent binary in iTunes Connect. : it's 'Ready for Sale'. (and currently, 'Ready for Upload' is added)

and some more checklists on Google

(For someone who are looking for the solution to IAP, I hope the checklist above may help you)

**+**

**more clues...**

1. I added a new IAP to another app which is Ready for sale.
   -> Still not working
2. I added a new IAP to another one which has never been released (prepare for upload).
   -> not working
3. in my MyApp-Info.plist, [Bundle identifier: com.my.app], [Bundle display name: MYAPP]
4. iTunes connect app name is different from 'bundle display name', like 'This is my app'.

This problem might be related to iTunes connect or my account setting. But I cannot figure it out till now.

Comment: Why didn't you test IAP when you were making the app? Once it's available for purchase, you've waited too long…

Comment: At first, I didn't think of including IAP, but after releasing, I wanted to add IAP. (I mean, after I released the first version of app, I wanted to add a new feature to my app as IAP)

Comment: You can safely ignore the comment by Alexsander. It's perfectly fine to add in-app-purchase later. I did this a couple of times.

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood. I thought you had added IAP to the app, then submitted, then realized it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my device was the problem.
if there are someone with the same problem, check the device first.

Comment: what kind of a problem? I'm stuck with IAP not working, but everything seems to be set up just right..

Comment: I had tried several proposals at stackoverflow, finally I ended up with this conclusion - it was the device, but ... a combination of Xcode 4.6.2 - ios7 beta @ iphone4 - itunes connect "changes?" due to near-term ios7 public release... 3 day debugging and testing, afterwards xcode5, ios7 release and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

> my IAP status is 'Waiting for Screenshot'

Fix this first, I.E. upload a screenshot. If I remember correctly I supplied a screenshot and the testing worked for me.

Comment: Uploading the screenshot is the first step. Then the IAP needs to be approved by Apple.

Comment: I doubt it, I started testing like 5 minutes after I created the product in itunes connect.

Comment: I uploaded about 6hrs ago... but sadly nothing's changed

Comment: I figured out long time ago that the problem was my device itself. Thank you for kind replies!

Answer (score 1):

Uploading the screenshot  and prove the apple that your  IAP was working correctly in sanbox account .by providing the screen shot below.

[image]